Gateway service does not get informed about an updated service port
I have a cluster of Spring Cloud services;

Eureka Server
Gateway
Client Service (port:0 so a random port is assigned on each startup)

When I start all the applications up, everything looks good. However, when I stop a running client service assuming that the service is down for any reason, and start that service up with a new port. Gateway does not get informed about the new port of the service. I get an exception in Gateway service console:
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /192.168.1.112:54720
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/api/product/health" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
...
...

From this message, I can understand that gateway has an old client service port. (new port is 54799)
What should I add or update an existing property so that a service with a new port registers to Eureka Server and Gateway service sends a request and gets new service information (ports) before routing.
I tried
eureka.client.registry-fetch-interval-seconds=5

in the gateway service application.properties file but it did not work out.
